# ComponentKit - How to vertically align components inside a horizontal stack layout

Tags: componentkit

I've just started using ComponentKit and seems really straightforward so far, but having a little trouble with flexbox. How would I go about vertically aligning components inside a horizontal CKStackLayoutComponent? What my first attempt was is to add another CKStackLayoutComponent as a child and set that to vertical, and add my components to that, but that crashes on launch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you include the crash log, and maybe some sample code and a screenshot of what you want?

Comment: Are you looking to align 3 items horizontally? or nest 2 items into a single item on top of each other? A - B - C with A at the top, B at the bottom and C centered vertically? or A - B/C with B and C vertically over each other?

Comment: Managed to accomplish this, see below

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys was able to fix this, the problem was because I had the CKStackLayoutComponent as a sub component of CKBackgroundLayoutComponent and I think I was trying to add more than one child when it expects only one child.

The way I fixed it was having a horizontal CKStackLayoutComponent and then having two children of CKStackLayoutComponent type, both vertical direction. This way you can have things aligned in two columns.